# How to mock @HeaderParam in mockito

Tags: mockito

how should I mock `@HeaderParam` for writing test cases in mockito ?

for example

`@HeaderParam("USER") 
private String userid;`

So I should be able to add mock values in `userid`

Answer (score 0):

For example, if the **userid** variable is a variable in **A.class** you need to annotate this class with **@Spy**.

```
A.class{

    @HeaderParam("USER") 
    private String userid;

    public void setUserId(String userid){
     this.userid=userid;
    }
    public String getUserId(String userid){
     return userid;
    }
}

testMethod(){
    @Spy
    A a;

    a.setUserId("Any String"); 

    a.getUserId(); //it equals "Any String"
}
```